# Karaf 4.0.6 - custom branding

Tags: karaf, branding

I have a problem with custom branding in Karaf 4.0.6. 
I've put branding.properties file into $KARAF_HOME/etc directory but the welcome message and prompt are still default.

Should I set up something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. In my case I run karaf as server and then connect via ssh. Since karaf 4.0.6 you have to use file branding-ssh.properties for clients.

[Here I found the answer](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Branding-properties-file-not-picked-up-by-Karaf-client-td4048143.html)

Answer (score -2):

Here a link to the latest docs: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_branding

Here a duplication of what the docs say (in case the link goes away):

I created a etc/branding.properties on a fresh installation of Karaf 4.0.6 and my branding changes, when I start it with karaf.bat (on Windows).
When starting with client.bat you need to change etc/branding-ssh.properties.

Comment: I don't do this by installing bundle. This is the second solution. I want to custom branding using simply branding.properties file.

Comment: Not gonna work. You definitely need to install the bundle.

Comment: I tried your approach with branding.properties on a fresh Karaf 4.0.6 and it works for me. How do you start Karaf?

Comment: It's my own custom version of package but starting is the same as in Karaf docs - ./karaf.sh